# a value of provider<AuthBase> cant be returned from the method build because it has a return type of widget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/services/auth.dart';



Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AuthBase>(
      create: (context) => Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Time tracker',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          home: LandingPage(
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi everyone as you can see the error from the title i cant continue the work I'm using provider: 4.3.2+2
which my instructor Andrea told me to use the the same version as his ...i searched but couldn't find the answer  I also tried the latest version of provider but it didn't work it gave me the same error. Is there anyone that can tell me where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution by myself . the problem  is with your dart  and flutter sdk .
delete them all and install them again . if you are installing the latest version of flutter you don't need to install dart saprately the path to your dart sdk lives inside of your flutter folder and another thing to notice is that check your ENV and you shoud'nt have a dart sdk varaible seprately if android studio want the path you can set it in the setting  language and framework dart section check the enable box and then set the dart sdk path
and you're done!